# Change text color of a column of dbc.Table

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash application. I have a dataframe coming from backend and in forntend, I am displaying that dataframe using `dbc.Table` component.

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
        "Result": ["Failed", "Passed", "Passed", "Failed"],
        
    }
)

table = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(df, striped=True, bordered=True, hover=True)
```

Currently, table is getting displayed with default text color. I am trying to display `Result` column with

```
Failed in Red color
Passed in Green color
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conditional cell style formatting is built-in for `dash.dash_table.DataTable` and overall table style can be customized to mimic `dbc`

Style can of course be changed/customized however you wish/imagine, but, e.g.,:

```py
import pandas as pd

import dash
from dash.dash_table import DataTable

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
        "Result": ["Failed", "Passed", "Passed", "Failed"],
    }
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        DataTable(
            data=df.to_dict("records"),
            sort_action="native",
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            style_data_conditional=[
                {
                    "if": {
                        "filter_query": '{Result} = "Passed"',
                        "column_id": "Result",
                    },
                    "color": "green",
                    "fontWeight": "bold",
                },
                {
                    "if": {
                        "filter_query": '{Result} = "Failed"',
                        "column_id": "Result",
                    },
                    "color": "red",
                    "fontWeight": "bold",
                },
                {
                    "if": {"row_index": "odd"},
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(210, 210, 220, 0.5)",
                },
            ],
            style_data={
                "color": "black",
                "backgroundColor": "white",
                "textAlign": "center",
            },
            style_header={
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.65)",
                "color": "black",
                "fontWeight": "bold",
                "textAlign": "center",
            },
        )
    ]
)

app.run(debug=True)
```

yields:
[image: Video screen shot recording showing dash DataTable with conditionally highlighted 'Results' column]